# Deploying Spring Cloud based micro services without docker

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix

I have basic setup of Eureka , Zuul , Config Server with two test micro services , Currently i need to start each of this services using **gradle bootRun** or using command 
**java -jar MyService-1.0.jar --server.port=8085** Is their any way where i can start all this spring boot application in one go (without docker) ?

Comment: You could write a script for it and run that, so it will start all of them at once. I made something similar to spin up a number of microservices for development.

Comment: hi @ÁkosRatku thanks for reply .can you give more idea on it or share some basic code to start two services together? it will be helpful .

Comment: What platform are you running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution and wrote **.bat** file for same and its working, if any better way then this please do reply

```
START cmd.exe /k "cd C:\Users\winuser\Code\Service1\build\libs & java -jar Service1.jar"
START cmd.exe /k "cd C:\Users\winuser\Code\Service2\build\libs & java -jar Service2.jar"
```

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this in unix:

To wakeup all the services:

**upAndSaveAllPid.sh**

```
nohup java -jar registration.jar my.log 2>&1 &
echo $! > pid_running.tmp
nohup java -jar greeting.jar my.log 2>&1 &
echo $! >> pid_running.tmp
nohup java -jar client-greeting.jar my.log 2>&1 &
echo $! >> pid_running.tmp
nohup java -jar HystrixDashboard.jar my.log 2>&1 &
echo $! >> pid_running.tmp 
nohup java -jar api-gateway.jar my.log 2>&1 &
echo $! >> pid_running.tmp
```

To kill all microservices:

**killAllPids.sh**

```
kill -9 `cat pid_running.tmp`
rm pid_running.tmp
```